# Python array: remove one dimension from a tuple that only has one 1D list

Tags: python

I have one tuple that only has one list element `a = ((3, 2, 2, 2, 2), )`, whose length is `1`; can I remove one dimension from it to achieve `(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)`, whose length is `5`? Thank you!

```
>>> a1 = ((3, 2, 2, 2, 2),)
>>> print(len(a1))
1
>>> a2 = (3, 2, 2, 2, 2) # How can I convert from a1 to a2? 
>>> print(len(a2))
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a2 = a1[0]
```

This works if `a1` actually contains an element, otherwise it raises an exception